# K8 changing node status to Not Ready

Tags: kubernetes

is there any way to temporarily mark a node as "Not Ready" in the k8s cluster? I am trying to reproduce a production issue where I need to mark the "Ready" Node as "Not Ready" with scheduling enabled.

Tried killing docker daemon in node, its marking node as "Not Ready".

Comment: Or put some memroy pressure on node !!

Comment: any suggestions on how to create memory pressure. I tried with stress-ng to consume 99% of available memory and no change in the node status

Answer (score 1):

killing docker daemon in node, its marking node as "Not Ready".